# SpringMVC Controller on resource not found on /

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am following up a tutorial from this url

```
https://aishwaryavaishno.wordpress.com/2013/07/12/spring-mvchibernate-annotation-based-mysql-maven-json-simple-example/
```

From the tutorial I have this in my controller

```
@Autowired
        private IMusicStoreService musicStoreService;
        @RequestMapping(value="/")
        public ModelAndView test(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{

            return new ModelAndView("home","musicDetForm",new MusicDetails());
        }
        @RequestMapping(value="AddSong",method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public String addSong(@ModelAttribute("musicDetForm") MusicDetails musicDetails){
           return musicStoreService.addSong(musicDetails);
        }
        @RequestMapping(value = "SongList/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public List<MusicDetails> getSongList(){
            return musicStoreService.getSongList();
        }
```

I have mapped my DispatcherServlet and contextConfigLocation to my web.xml file

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

Assuming that this is my default url from the controller mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value="/")
        public ModelAndView test(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{

            return new ModelAndView("home","musicDetForm",new MusicDetails());
        }
```

Now when I launch my application to this url

```
http://localhost:8080/MusicStore/
```

A screenshot of my project structure

[image]

Tomcat which is my servlet engine returns HTTP Status Error 404.

Please what could be wrong?

[image: Error Notification]

Comment: Please share your Exception Stack Trace and If it is saying 404 Error, it is not hitting the server may be problem with your project packaging structure. And please post your project package structure too for analysis.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have added a screenshot of my project structure

Comment: your project structure doesn't formed correctly, as I see your HomeController.java as a class file. It is not recognized as a Java file. That's why you are getting this exception, I have edited to show the error indication, once peer reviewed it will visible to you. Also, please post eclipse project facet settings.

Comment: @PraveenKumar My Project Facet I have Java, Javascript and Dynamic Web Module ticked

Comment: My runtime engine is Tomcat 8.0

Comment: @PraveenKumar Please how do I make my HomeController.java recognized as a Java file

Comment: In Eclipse if your java file is showing in a hollow shade, then it is a class file.. Please check if you have duplicate of this HelloController file. Also, you expand everything in your project structure and post the stack trace, will be easy for figuring it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110526/discussion-between-jng-and-praveen-kumar).

Comment: There is no error on my stacktrace so it could be that tomcat is not seeing my controller class.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I can see error on my stacktrace

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917191/java-io-filenotfoundexception-could-not-open-servletcontext-resource-web-inf

Answer (score 0):

put the following code in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml to configure viewResolver

```
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
```

then add your jsp file in /WEB-INF/views/

Comment: Your may miss to add context:component-scan tag in dispatcher-servlet configuration file     add following  line    <context:component-scan base-package="package name in which your controller class reside" />

Comment: It is there. Please check Praveen Edit on my question. How can I make eclipse recognize my .java file which is the controller

Comment: @JNG, Don't import the project directly in your IDE, please create a dynamic web project by copy/pasting individually.

Answer (score -1):

Have you configured viewResolver ?

@Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {

```
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setPrefix("/");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);

    return resolver;
}
```

Comment: Cant this be xml based?

Comment: add this to your configuration xml file. Change jsp file path if necessary
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
 </bean>